# Is null matrix skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is:
Is null matrix skew-symmetric?
I think it is true as **A'=-A** is trivially satisfied for a null matrix.

Please help.

Comment: Yes. (It's also symmetric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a matrix is skew symmetric, you need to show that:
$$-A=A^T$$
For example in the case of $2\times 2$ matrices, you need:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-a&-b\\-c&-d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{bmatrix}$$

When we set $a=b=c=d=0$ this is trivially satisfied.

---

Also this is satisfied non-trivially for example in the reals, when $-a=a,-b=c,d=-d$, say:

$$M_c=\begin{bmatrix}0&-c\\c&0\end{bmatrix}:c\in \Bbb R$$

Clearly $-M_c = \begin{bmatrix}0&c\\-c&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $M_c^T = \begin{bmatrix}0&c\\-c&0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

A skew-symmetric (or antisymmetric) matrix is a square matrix A, whose transpose is also its negative ($A'=-A$).

A null (or zero) matrix is an $m \times n$ matrix with all its entries being zero.

If the zero matrix is a square matrix, it satisfies the properties for skew-symmetricity. (if $m \neq n$, it is not skew-symmetric)

Comment: You are right, I have edited it now.